# Android Chrome Lite mode breaks our website. Deactivates Javascript. (Google Chrome data saver)

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

We are having a hard time with Google Chrome in Android devices. It loads our website in "lite mode" this mode deactivates the scripts, this breaks many functionalities of our website like the menu...

I have seen the lite mode is activated for other websites but it does not deactivate javascript, I would like to know why in our case the "lite mode" is deactivating scripts.

Any idea?